# Single Page Or Multi Page Web Application?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, web

I am creating a web Application with node js,angular,mysql and and express.Application contains different type of record which i have to manage.
So what do i use Single Page Application or Multi Page Application.

Comment: i guess if you are using angularjs, it should be SPA

Answer (score 2):

To me it comes down to preference and how much work I want to put into my application. Since you are using Angular, I think having the luxury of doing a single page application is great because load time is minimal.

If you take the multi page direction I would suggest ditching Angular and serving files from the server. The benefit of that is that you don't have to handle two applications.

I would use Angular because single page applications are very user friendly right now.

Good luck with your decision.